# Rename or delete the "cv" tag

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There is a question that has been tagged with [cv](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv). I think the tag should be renamed to [curriculum-vitae](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/curriculum-vitae), or deleted.

#### Update

There are now 13 questions tagged [cv](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv).

Comment: Re: the update, the *cv* tag also has a detailed tag wiki, which sounds like whoever wrote it certainly believed the tag to be on-topic and useful. If we want to get rid of this tag, the tag wiki should reflect that fact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do we really need a [cv](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cv) tag, regardless of what it’s called? We’re not in the business of critiquing résumés.

Comment: Agreed, let's get rid of it.